# How should swordfish be prepared?

Tags: fish

I just purchased one pound of swordfish filet and never cooked swordfish before and have minimal experience cooking fish. Any suggestions on preparation? Also what should I look for while cooking it?

Comment: Swordfish is on the red list of fish to avoid due to over fishing. In the old days I would have rubbed with muscovado (raw brown sugar) and some dried oregano and rosemary, gentle BBQ with the lid on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love swordfish grilled with a little olive oil and Montreal steak spice.  All the firm fish are great on the grill.

Firm fish like ahi tuna and swordfish can pretty much be treated like really good steak, just cook them carefully because you want them left on the very-rare side of things.

If you do it in a pan make sure there's hot oil or butter (or both) before you add the fish and don't move it around too much.  If you fuss too much with the fish it will fall apart.

As delicious as swordfish is a lot of the fish on the market isn't being sustainably caught.  Make sure to ask where its coming from.  Most of the US and Canada fisheries are pretty good.

Comment: It is from the US and Canada, I forget where specifically. Whole foods had "wild swordfish steaks" on sale for $11.99 lb, so I had to pull the trigger on it

Comment: all swordfish is wild. I don't think you would want to try keeping one in any form of enclosure...

Answer (score 1):

Olive oil, salt and pepper and grilled (on a flame broiler or outside Bar-B-Que) to perfection.  Then, when done, squeeze some lemon (or, in my case, lime) on top and enjoy...  Most fishes, I think, taste best with the simple additions, but others will disagree because it's a matter of taste.  One spice mix, therefore, I personally love on any fish, including sword fish is a nice mix I got on Orcas island: chipotle, ancho, cumin, some green herbs (dried) and salt and pepper...

Answer (score 0):

Ginger+garlic paste+red chilli powder+olive oil+salt+lemon & grill it..

Answer (score 0):

When caught we normally gut them. stuff with lemon grass & pit roast.